# Unfortunately "app_name" has stopped in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, monodevelop

After upgrading to **Xamarin 4.3.0.784**, my app is crashing every time. And I am getting notification "one or more errors occurred" in **Xamarin.Android.common.Debugging.Targets** file under **GetPrimaryCpuAbi** tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research about this issue on few days ago, I can give you some tips on the following:

1-try to **disable Fast Deployment** in android build options(Release Mode).

2-try to **disable Shared Shared Runtime** in android build options(Release Mode).

3-actually you did not need to **enable all architectures check-boxes** under Supported architectures.

and if you want to Deal with Startup Crashes, check the following link:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/platform-features/advanced-topics/dealing-with-startup-crashes/

and to avoid **Xamarin.forms** app crashes for unknown reason, try to get latest stable version of **Xamarin.forms** package from nuget.org.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. I opened the project with visual studio, disabled "Use shared runtime",  enabled all supported architectures. After restarting, now it is working.

Comment: disabling those are not recommended i believe. That means something is wrong with your code. You can just observe output window to see why it is crashing. in debug mode Output window will always show you information, In Release mode however you can get information using Android Device Monitor